# How to wrap Angular 2 events and properties

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Instead of directly applying **[disabled]="true"** in the HTML code, like this:

```
<button [disabled]="true"> disable Button </button>
     //or like this
<button [disabled]="isDisabled()"> disable Button </button>
```

I want to ***wrap Angular2* [disable] *event or property*** to look something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<button ButtonFunc.isDisabled(true)> disable Button </button>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
export class ButtonFunc { 

  constructor(){}


  public isDisabled( disabledState : boolean ) : boolean{
    [disabled]=disabledState;
  }
}
```

I want this function `ButtFunc.isDisabled()` to do the job of disabling HTML Button for me.

Is it possible to 'radically' eliminate Angular2 from the HTML file and to wrap it in low-level class, and then to call and use that Angualr2 from that low-level class over functions? And how to do that?

Comment: `disabled` is not an event, it's a property. To me it's entirely unclear what your question is about. There is no way to customize the Angular binding syntax. What's wrong with `[disabled]="isDisabled"`? Binding to methods is a bad idea in general in Angular. It can cause severe performance issues. Assign the result to a field and bind to that field instead.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with [disabled]="isDisabled" but I need to go step further, to eliminate all Angular Libraries and syntax and to put them in my low-level classes, and then to use them (events, properties) over mine classes.
I'll try to form the question in a better way.

Comment: "eliminate all Angular Libraries and syntax" sounds like just not adding Angular to your project does that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking more for this:

```
<button [disabled]="isDisabled()"> disable Button </button>

isDisabled(){
return calculated && this.available // for example
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's typical way of combining functions and angular properties... but I was required to go step further. So I'm exploring is it possible to replace *[disabled]="isDisabled()"* with only isDisabled().